# Which image file formats can be embedded in posts on Cross Validated?

Tags: support, images

The question is in the title: which different image/animation file formats can be embedded here? I have searched around without finding any list of formats.

Answer (score 6):

Not a complete list.

These definitely work:

PNG, JPEG, GIF

examples of the first two are easy to locate; the third can be done, as shown [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369254/330679) for example, or on our own site [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153726/proof-of-algebraic-formula-for-the-sum-of-two-dice-toss-as-a-convolution/153775#153775).

<s>Pretty sure these won't work (currently at least)</s>

<s>SVG</s>

I haven't spotted a bmp or a tiff yet (and not certain stack.imgur.com supports those), but there might be ways to do them. However, the fact that on stackoverflow many posts discuss BMP files but display PNG files when talking about them (e.g. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823509/inverting-colors-of-pixels-in-a-bmp-file-in-c)) suggests that maybe BMP files are either not possible or may be possible but might be actively discouraged (if so, presumably for space reasons); if that's the case TIFF files would have similar issues.

Comment: Wondering if this should be community wiki

Comment: I made a couple of my posts CW years ago, & I was told that it wasn't necessary on meta. I think that's right; I see no reason why this would need to be CW.

Comment: I guess there's no points at stake at least. Well, people should feel free to just edit anything they can support into the answer if they wish

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the point (or lack thereof...).

Comment: Imgur's help center has an entry: [What files can I upload? What is the size limit?](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000083326-What-files-can-I-upload-What-is-the-size-limit-), though it seems SE also customized some filter on the front end (e.g. [PDF was supported before, but not now](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3457/is-imgur-pdf-upload-broken))

Comment: Thanks. I located that page in attempting to answer this question, but was unsure the extent to which that applied to uploads to stack.imgur.com --

Answer (score 4):

#### There are other options that work, albeit not via imgur

Basically anything that works with the html tag `<img>` [but this is browser dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)

---

#### Examples

**BMP**

[image: plot]

**SVG**

[image: plot]